# How do I enable Google Now on my Galaxy Note 2 (NT-7100)?

Tags: google-now, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I go to Google Search app but no Google Now "cards" are showing.

I do the ff:

1. Long-press Menu soft-key to bring up Google Search
2. Press Menu -> Settings
3. Under settings, I only get 3 entries: Voice, Phone search and Privacy & accounts (no Google Now)

My friend, who uses an HTC Sensation with MIUI ROM, and Google Now works nicely.

Question is, how do I enable it on my Note 2?

**I am suspecting that this has to do with my Privacy settings or Location settings but I still haven't gotten it to work despite changing those settings...*

Comment: I wouldn't think that it's to do with your location services, I know that if I have "Access to my location" turned off in "Location Access" in the phone's settings, then as soon as I open Google Now the first card says: "***Location service is off***: *To continue using Google Now, you need to turn on Google's locations service*" with a link to the relevant section in Settings.

Comment: Is it country-locked? Where are you located?

Comment: The answer has already been provided. It was with the Language setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language setting was my key problem - after changing the OS language from Croatian to English (U.S.), Google Now is miraculously ready to go!

Watch the video [How to get Google Now talking to you...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNS-0XS4Kag) for an instructional guide on changing your system language.

Comment: This solved the issue. I had to change the language to English (United States) to get it working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must be running at least Android 4.1 to use Google Now - please ensure this is true.

If you *are* running at least Android 4.1, then ensure you have the latest Google Voice Search update from the Google Play Store - be aware that it is listed twice (at least on my old device).

Comment: The Galaxy Note 2 I got had 4.1 out-of-the-box. I have also updated Google Search and Google Voice Search doesn't have an Update option when I checked today.

Comment: @Eric Strange. Have you tried clicking on the voice search widget?

Comment: Yes. Still no "Google Now" in the Settings menu

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you are running the latest version of Google Search? The easiest way to update is to visit the Google Play Store page for [Google Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) and check to see if it will allow you to install or update the app.

Ok, so I found how to turn on Google Now on my GN2. If you have the Google search widget, it is as simple as hitting the settings button (left light-up one) while inputting a query for the search widget. This brings up a menu, hit settings then you can turn on Google Now.

I accidentally opted out when in early setup, and now I am curious.

Comment: Yes. I uninstalled updates and re-installed updates but Google Now still isn't showing under "Settings" in Google Search

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I think this is how you do it.

Open Google Search from the app drawer. Tap on menu and then settings, then tap Google Now - you should be able to toggle it on from there.

Comment: Oops, just saw your other post about Google Now not showing in settings of Google Search.  Seems pretty odd.  I wonder if you need to do a factory reset?  The other thing to do before that maybe is just to try clearing data in Google search?

Comment: I have tried clearing Google Search data to no avail. :( I guess I will try to do a Factory reset soon because I too think that this is the last resort. Thanks for contributing.